# Obtener Certificado Digital para ocupar aplicacion web en navegador de Servidor MVC5

Tags: c#, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, iis, certificado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ayuda necesito saber como puedo obtener el certificado digital desde el servidor, localmente me funciona perfecto, pero al momento de publicarlo, me da un error en el LOG el cual me indica que El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado., necesito correr el sistema directamente desde el servidor.

Comment: Revisa los derechos del pool sobre la carpeta donde tienes el certificado, otra cosa que pasa a veces es cuando en el IIS pones la ruta por puerto como: web.com:234, o por ruta como  web.com/aplicacion, creo que cuadno lo corres local por default estas en localhost:43542, puedes correr tu visual como administrador, desde el menu abrir el proyecto, darle click dercho configuracion y cambiar IIS express por LOCAL IIS y publicarlo como en tu server para validar esto mismo, primero instala IIS en tu ambiente local.

Comment: Nos dejas ver el codigo con el que recuperar el certificado, por favor.

Comment: @MichaelOspina tengo dos metodos con los cuales puedo recuperar el certificado, le dejo los dos:

Comment: public static X509Certificate2 obtenerCertificado()
 {
string certificadoURL = "";
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/CertificadoDigital/CertificadoDigital.pfx");
 certificadoURL = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/CertificadoDigital/CertificadoDigital.pfx");
 string certificadoPASS = "123";
var PrivateKeyHash = File.ReadAllBytes(certificadoURL);
 var certificado = new X509Certificate2(PrivateKeyHash, certificadoPASS);
 return certificado;
        }

Comment: @MichaelOspina solo le pude dejar un metodo el otro es muy largo y no lo acepta